# You need at least 15 <a href="/help/whats-reputation">reputation</a> to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, notifications, popup

[image: bug]

First post here. Very minor UI bug - was upvoting the question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/67887/253552). I don't have enough reputation though.
A popup comes up like this. The popup contains raw HTML rather than text. Tried refreshing the page several times, but it didn't change. Is this is a problem because of my browser or the site?

Comment: It's a site bug, which has already been reported. It's actually not as minor as you might think, and it is breaking pop-up notifications all over the place.

Comment: Hick-up of pop-up.